# Should a high score question that is not within posting rules be closed?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I was reviewing the close queue and bumped into this question:

[Using Git and Dropbox together effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively)

asking

> Is there a good tutorial where I can learn using Git and Dropbox
>   together effectively?

The question itself seems to be a good candidate for close as

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

but it currently has 633 upvotes and seems to be very popular.

Should such questions be closed or should I leave it open altough it does not comply with rules, but it is very popular?

Comment: It's from the early days of SO... a historical lock would be appropriate.

Comment: Most answers don't rely on off-site resources. So it should be possible to edit it so this close reason no longer applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ask you the opposite question: why should it not be closed?

The close reason applies. Ergo, the question should be closed.

There is a bit of historical context which supplements this answer, and it can be summarized as follows: in the Days of Yore, such questions were acceptable and welcome. The community has decided they are no longer accepted - but the votes from years ago do not reflect this change.

Comment: Well I did vote to close - but felt the guilt of 633 upvotes.

Comment: Don't worry about it :] VTC is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Don't see how many votes does a questions have. If a questions is off-topic as per [current standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), just vote/flag to close it. There are lots of [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=votes:100%20closed:yes) with more than 100 votes. Normally people tend to upvote questions which are off-topic but useful for them. Closed questions will just prevent additional answers. People can still search such questions if not deleted. And mostly such helpful questions are not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Closing wouldn't prevent users from criss-cross upvotes or comments 'but I think this **is useful** for me'. Such topics have a lot of value for internet community, but the problem is, they are obviously **off-topic now** and they provide a bad example for the community. As long as they are simply closed, they would attract reopen votes they don't deserve.

They are perfect candidates for **historical lock** and I've flagged the post to lock as such. In my opinion, they should be converted one by one to blog entries.

Spoiling review queue is something separate, and not more a problem in that case, because as fair as I know, the question that have gotten at least one close vote ever in the past, won't appear as review audit.